# two factor authentication for a wifi network?

Tags: android-wifi, two-factor-authentication, network-security, wifi

is it possible to setup two factor authentication for known users of a wifi network?  I imagine that this might add security to wifi networks whose keys are stored by an untrusted device or third party smartphone os-maker.

Comment: You can bind mac address with user authentication which increases the network security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we can apply on Cisco Router(as much as I know) and we have the following options:

- OTP using external RADIUS server and RSA tokens
- EAP-Chaining using the AnyConnect Agent and Cisco ISE
- MAR (machine access restrictions).  If the machine had not performed authentication the user will not be authorized
- Layer 3 security on the Wireless LAN Controller